# VB 2010 Convert UTC Date to dd-MMM-yyyy format

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, time, format, utc

I get the UTC Date and Time using:

```
Dim UTCN As Date = (Date.UtcNow)
```

It outputs 8/19/2012 3:48:24 PM

I need to FTP a file that must use the format dd-MMM-yyyy (19-Aug-2012)

My problem is that I must use UTC and it must be in the above format. This will run in various time zones so I do not want to use a fixed offset to convert local to UTC. I know how to FTP and everything else but I can not figure out how can I format **UTCM** to meet my needs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Date.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it out puts 8/19/2012 not what I need. I need it formatted as:19-AUG-2010

Comment: Strange. It is working for me. Please post the code you used.

Comment: I am sorry you are correct, please accept my apologies.... I used Dim UTCM As Date when I should have used: Dim UTCN As String = (Date.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")) Once again Thank you!!!